# Using git as a deployment tool

Tags: git, bash, deployment

I am trying to use git as a deployment tool, so when there has been a push to the production branch I want to update the remote server accordingly. However, when I run the second command(the pull) it comes back with a error that says `Operation must be run in a work tree.` Can anyone point me in the right direction?

Here is a partial sample of the bash script.

```
echo -e "Thank you for pushing your changes to ${project}. \nHold on while I update the required directories..."
GIT_WORK_TREE=/home/www/${project} git checkout -f
echo "Local directory updated!"

for ref in $@; do
    echo $ref
    if [ "$ref" = "refs/heads/production" ]; then
        # Before we could set the GIT directory strictly from the local environment
        # but the case might not be the same remotely. Need absolute paths.
        ssh git@myserver GIT_DIR=/home/www/${project}/.git GIT_WORK_TREE=/home/www/${project} git checkout -f production
        ssh git@myserver.com GIT_DIR=/home/www/${project}/.git GIT_WORK_TREE=/home/www/${project} git pull -f production
        echo "Production push completed"
    fi
done
```

EDIT:

Here is the copy pasted error:

`remote: fatal: /usr/lib/git-core/git-pull cannot be used without a working tree.`

Comment: You should look into [Capistrano](https://github.com/capistrano/capistrano) instead of rolling your own deploy scripts.

Comment: Git is not a deployment tool, though with sufficient scripting it can kinda sorta work that way.  See http://toroid.org/ams/git-website-howto  But yes, maegar is right, it needs to be non-bare (and should not typically be the primary upstream server copy but rather a repo you specifically push to).

Answer (score 4, accepted):

As @meagar said it sounds like the cloned repository on the remote server was cloned with the `--bare` option. Clone it again without this option to get a normal "working directory" copy, like you have locally.

So you should now have:

- your local repository
- a bare repository on the server
- a normal one on the server (cloned from the bare one)

With that in mind you can now create a post-receive hook which is run whenever something is pushed to the bare repository. Hooks live (on the server) in the bare repo's hooks folder (there are samples in there for various cases).

```
#!/bin/bash
while read oldrev newrev refname
do
    if [ "$refname" == "refs/heads/master" ]; then
        WORKDIR=/path/to/checked/out/repository
        export GIT_DIR=$WORKDIR/.git
        pushd $WORKDIR >/dev/null
        git pull --quiet >/dev/null
        # run some scripts in the checked out repository
        popd >/dev/null
    fi
done
```

This script specifically looks for a push to the master branch, but this can be easily changed to another branch or removed entirely. It then switches to the working directory of your checked out repository and does a pull. Once the pull is done you can run any other useful bash commands.

Comment: Ghickman -- I am doing this remotely, should I add all of those commands on one line with my SSH call?

Comment: @hwrdprkns - Nope that goes in <bare repo>/hooks/post-receive (make sure it's got execute permissions). As I said in my answer a post-receive hook is run automatically when you push to that bare repository from your local checkout so each time you push, it will update the server's checked out copy.

Comment: I don't think you understood me correctly -- this an example of my workflow: commit locally --> push to bare repo --> on post receive hook updates remote(keyword) repo on production server. Your script just seems like it updates a repository on the local server(w.r.t the bare-repo).

Comment: @hwrdprkns - sorry is your bare repo not on the remote server? This is a fairly standard way of using a bare repo, so I'd just assumed that's what you meant! It would certainly be far easier for you to put the bare repo on the remote server.

Answer (score 1):

It sounds like the repo you consider "deployed" is a bare repository. You should clone your repo **without** `--bare` and try again.